# replacement of string using regular expression at Xth position intervals (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, position

I would very much appreciate some assistance from the community on replacing a string at xth position intervals, using javascript regex.  For example, if the string length is 161 and the replacement text is `<br />`, regex would replace the string at the 40th, 80th, 120th, and 160th positions with this replacement text.  Is this possible using regex?

Thank you very much.

Comment: While it may be possible with regex, why not use other techniques to do this? It seems to me that you want to insert something every (n % 40 == 0) position.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Why not other techniques?  Because my logic thinks regex would require less lines of code and could be the simplest.  I'm open to other techniques, however.

Comment: Less lines of code doesn't necessarily make it neither simpler nor more efficient. Just a thing to note.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I appreciate your advice.  Note: That's why I said 'could' and not 'will' in my above comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method to add `<br />` at ever 40th position is by using the following line:

```
string = string.replace(/([\S\s]{40})/g , "$1<br />");
```

If you want to dynamically set the position use:

```
var positions = 40;
var pattern = new RegExp("([\\s\\s]{" + positions + "})", "g");
string = string.replace(pattern , "$1<br />");
```

**Explanation of the code**:

1. The first argument of the `replace` function is a RegExp:

   - (`[\S\s]` = all non-whitespace and white-space characters = every character).
   - `{40}` = 40 characters
   - The `g` flag means: global match, ie: match every possible occurence
   - The parentheses inside the RegExp means: Create a group. This group can later be referred by `$1` (first group)
2. The second argument of the `replace` function contains `$1<br />`. That is: replace the full match by the first group (`$1`), and add `<br />` to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  It is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "12345678901234567890";
var newStr = str.replace(/(.{5})/g,"$1<br/>");
```

for every 40, change the 5 to 40.