# replacing regex at nth position only not working

Tags: javascript, regex

My text is

```
<DIV STYLE="text-align:Left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12;color:#000000;"><P STYLE="font-family:Arial;margin:0 0 0 0;"><SPAN STYLE="font-family:Segoe UI;"><SPAN>{firstname} will continue to learn high frequency words, try to remember words and us them in their writing. {firstname} always uses correct spacing in their writing and attempts to use punctuation.</SPAN></SPAN></P></DIV>
```

So now i want to replace the **{firstname}** at index **202** with **{firstname_C}**

My code here doesnot work

```
var endIndex = 202;
var pattern = new RegExp("({firstname}{" + endIndex + "})", "g");
                commentString = commentString.replace("({firstname})/g", "{firstname_C}");
```

Referred to this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930869/replacement-of-string-using-regular-expression-at-xth-position-intervals-javasc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{` and `}` are special characters in regexp, you have to escape them in pattern:

Try:

```
commentString.replace(/\{firstname\}/g, '{firstname_C}')
```

Comment: i tried your solution: commentString = commentString.replace(/\{firstname\}{202}/g, "{firstname_C}");

Comment: That works for me perfectly: `'{firstname} will continue to learn high frequency words, try to remember words and us them in their writing. {firstname} always uses correct spacing in their writing and attempts to use punctuation.'.replace(/\{firstname\}/g, '{firstname_C}')`

Comment: problem is i need to replace at a specific index only..you have not included index 202 in your code

Comment: if you know the index already, why regexp? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236235/how-to-replace-a-string-at-a-particular-position

Comment: c'mon I am just trying to help. You determined the SPECIFIC index in whatever way you did, so THE INDEX IS KNOWN DURING RUNTIME and you know the EXACT LENGTH of the text you going to replace. Try figuring the solution yourself without regexp.